# How to start a exec() PHP command using a cron but not have 2 of them running?

Tags: php, cron, exec, centos

I just can't figure this out.
I have a script that gets data from Facebook API and this script runs all the time. (using set_time_limit(0); )

However, sometimes the Facebook API gives errors and stops the script. Therefor, I would like to have a cron task every 5 minutes or so that checks to see if the script is still running and if not, starts it again.

I tried several things but it looks like I cannot run a exec() command from a cron job because of different user rights or something? How would you guys do this?

I use CentOS and PHP 5.3+

Comment: What do you need to `exec()`. Can't you just execute it from the crontask?

Comment: Does Facebook have streaming API similar to Twitter? That would be the only reason to have a script like that that runs all the time, otherwise you don't need to do it like that, can just start new script every 5 minutes, parse your response and exit.

Comment: @PeeHaa + Dmitri I almost think this whole question is stupid now. The script is actually similar to a Twitter Streaming API script so I think that's where it went wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the cron under a different user (say, root), which will get around any rights issues. However, PeeHaa makes a good point: if this is a cron script, there's no reason to use exec, as exec's job is to send commands out to the OS... these commands can be run directly from the crontab rather than having cron execute a php file.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into creating a Daemon which is better suited to running a script continuously.  You can create one using PHP with this PEAR package [System_Daemon](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon/download)

Comment: He, that looks very nice. Thanks Justin.

Comment: For those interested: Here's a nice tutorial http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/

Answer (score 0):

If this process runs very frequently, run it in an endless loop and just sleep it. No need for crontabs.

```
while(true) {

   //magical code stuff

   sleep(60);

}
```